# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration

Tags: maven, postgresql-9.1, applicationcontext, spring-4, hibernate-4.x

i have created a maven project and added **Spring4, Hibernate4** libs through pom.xml
I m trying to link my web app with my database created in **PostgreSql**, but when i publish my project in **apache tomcat 7** the following exception occurs :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration,
>   and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name
>   either    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider specified
>   in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo
>   does not specify a provider class name either     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     ... 21 more

here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.medsoft.stadto">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1993/Posts" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="123" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="emf">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.medsoft.stadto.entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the `emf` bean configuration and add a new bean called `jpaVendorAdapter`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="emf">
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.medsoft.stadto.entity" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="stadto"/>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
  <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
  <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
  <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
</bean>
```

Also make sure you have a `persistence.xml` in the `META-INF` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">
  <persistence-unit name="stadto">
    //No need to specify the provider as we already have specified JPA vendor in applicationContext.xml
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do without using perssistence.xml ? Can you explain what his vendor adaptor does ?

Comment: There is a way to do without using persistence.xml. You can create LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with hibernates jpa vendor adapter;  @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean directoryManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;}

Answer (score 5):

It happens when you don't configure JpaVendorImplementation for JPA. The below Java bean definition for JPA EntityManager works for me:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emf.setPackagesToScan(irdbConfig.getPathForPackagesToScan());
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    emf.setJpaPropertyMap(irdbConfig.getAdditionalHibernateProperties());
    return emf;
}
```

But the below one throws same exception you received:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emf.setPackagesToScan(irdbConfig.getPathForPackagesToScan());        
    return emf;
}
```

Please notice the lines which are removed from the second code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to provide the `HibernatePersistenceProvider` for the `JpaPropertyMap` like this.

```java
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.example.testservice.entity");
        Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        //** Set the JPA provider explicitly (Hibernate)
        emf.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        emf.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        return emf;
    }
```